# Which NFS server should we use on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, solaris, nfs

We need to serve NFS shares from our Windows Server 2008 R2 machine to Solaris 5.10 clients, since apparently we are unable to mount SMB shares on our Solaris 5.10 machines :( What's the recommended NFS server technology on this platform? Is Windows services for UNIX a good alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rtacconi's answer is dated and would apply for 2003, not 2008.

Windows 2008 R2 has a stock NFS server.  NFS Basically just acts as another protocol.  If you install the role, NFS is a tab under SHARING.

We use it to serve up over 500K files to Centos 5.5 boxes in our web cluster.

Seems to work pretty well.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing your experiences with the stock NFS server!

Comment: We will be testing the stock NFS server over the next few days, to see if it's production ready. Hopefully it'll work well enough for our purposes :)

Comment: Yes I have not used 2008 at all.

Answer (score 1):

HOW TO: Set Up Server for NFS: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324086.

Why you cannot mount SMB shares on Solaris?

Comment: Keep in mind my question is not how to set up NFS/Windows Services for UNIX :) I haven't tried setting up SMB myself, rather our IT guys said it wasn't possible with the particular version of Solaris 5.10 (we need an older version for compatibility reasons).

Answer (score 0):

I think the least frustrating option is to setup a unix-based (in your case Solaris 5.10) NFS server.

I am not aware of any 3rd party NFS server app for Windows? So if you don't want the easy option of a Solaris-based NFS server, stick to rtacconi's answer.

Another option is to migrate your Solaris 5.1 environment to a virtual machine/instance/box and have them share files with the host machine's mapped network drive.

Comment: There is no question of switching to a UNIX server. We have a dedicated Windows server, and the only problem is our 5.10 clients don't support SMB. I found at least one 3rd party Windows NFS server at http://www.hanewin.net/nfs-e.htm. Your virtual Solaris box suggestion is an interesting one though, I'll keep it in mind!

Comment: That 3rd party software you link to predates Windows 2003. I would expect Windows's built-in NFS service, as mentioned by rtacconi on this page, will do a better job. I'm sure it's easier to do in Windows 2008.